# How to read all text with </xliff:g> tag by using ElementTree for python

Tags: android, python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to read and check all text from Android string.xml file.

the file contains below content:

```
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
<string name="status">Finishing <xliff:g id="number">%d</xliff:g> percent.</string>
</resources>
```

I tried:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse(filepath)
root = tree.getroot()

print len(root[0])
# it prints 1

print root[0].text
# it prints Finishing 

print root[0][0].text
#it prints %d
```

How to find a way to print the 3rd text, "percent.", while `<xliff:g>` tag is gettng in my way.
Any proper way to do it? thanks

Comment: Excellent first question: sample XML, expected output, and attempted codes along with its current output. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `ElementTree`, your target text "percent." is modeled as `tail` of the element `xliff:g` :

```
>>> ns = {"xliff": "urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2"}
>>> g = root.find("string/xliff:g", namespaces=ns)
>>> print g.tail
 percent.
```

Or using something closer to your attempted code :

```
>>> print root[0][0].tail
 percent.
```